# Custom function inside onAdd:

Tags: javascript, reactjs, electron

I have an issue with my code. I'm new to react and electron, so maybe is a easy question (I hope). Basically I'm creating a sortable list and I want to call a function I made inside the onEnd:

Even if I used .bind to bind the function to this, when onEnd git executed, I get that storeMyData is not defined. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks everybody

```
    sortableGroupDecorator(componentBackingInstance){
        // check if backing instance not null
        if (componentBackingInstance) {    
            var sortable = Sortable.create(componentBackingInstance, {
                    draggable: "img", // Specifies which items inside the element should be sortable
                    group: "shared",
                    animation: 150,
                    filter: ".ignore-elements",
                    onEnd: function (/**Event*/evt) {
                        this.storeMyData(componentBackingInstance.id)
                    }
                });
        }
    };
```

Comment: is `sortableGroupDecorator` inside a `class`? an arrow function like `onEnd: (evt) => ...` or extracting it to a separate function and bind it in the constructor may help here

Comment: it is inside a class 
class SortableList extends React.Component{
....
}